# Notification Bubble not showing

Tags: android, notifications

for some reason whenever I send a notification the notification bubble does not show up. Ive allowed notification bubbles from the developer options and compileSdkVersion is 29. Bubble activity just has a button in it for testing purposes. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = mContext.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

            // set up notification channel
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            // create person
            Person person = new Person.Builder()
                    .setName("Notification")
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(mContext, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setBot(true)
                    .setImportant(true)
                    .build();

            // create bubble meta data
            Intent target = new Intent(mContext, BubbleActivity.class);
            PendingIntent bubbleIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, target, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Notification.BubbleMetadata bubbleMetadata = new Notification.BubbleMetadata.Builder()
                    .setDesiredHeight(300)
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(mContext, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setSuppressNotification(true)
                    .setAutoExpandBubble(false)
                    .setIntent(bubbleIntent)
                    .build();

            // create message style
            Notification.MessagingStyle style = new Notification.MessagingStyle(person)
                    .setGroupConversation(false)
                    .addMessage("notification", currentTimeMillis(), person);

            // create notification intent
            Intent target2 = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), LaunchActivity.class);
            PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(), 1, target2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            // create notification
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification")
                    .setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithResource(mContext, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setLargeIcon(Icon.createWithResource(mContext, R.drawable.ic_notification))
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                    .setStyle(style)
                    .setBubbleMetadata(bubbleMetadata)
                    .addPerson(person)
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setContentIntent(notificationIntent)
                    .build();

            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
            }

        }
```

Comment: you need to push dynamic shortup first before send notification

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a shortcut ID on the notification. Once that is done, your notifications will appear in the conversation space and will be allowed to bubble. Note though that bubbles will not initially bubble automatically. It is up to the user to invoke/trigger this.

Please the following resources:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/conversations#api-shortcuts

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setShortcutId(java.lang.String)